# ¿Porque me llega la variable SESSION vacía o NULL?

Tags: php, sesiones

¡Hola!, resulta que al crear la sesion de usuario y enviar el dato hacia otra pagina (cabe recalcar en un hosting ), me manda un valor null , en el cuál , antes no pasaba eso , funcionaba todo correctamente,hace unos dias empezó con ello , inserto codigo :

```
session_start();

$stmr = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE NOMBRE = ? AND PASSWORD = ? ");
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"] ?: "";
$password = $_POST["password"] ?: "";
$stmr->bind_param("ss", $usuario, $password);
$stmr->execute();

$resultadoCons = $stmr->get_result();
if ($resultadoCons->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $resultadoCons->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["ID_TIPO"] == 1) {
            $_SESSION["administrador"] = $usuario;
            echo "administrador";
        } else if ($row["ID_TIPO"] == 3) {
            $_SESSION["admin"] = $usuario;
            echo "admin";
        } else {
            $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario;

            echo "usuario";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "error";
}
$con->close();
```

Ese es el codigo para validar al usuario y cuando intento conseguir el valor de la session me indica que esta vacio ,por ejemplo : `var_dump($_SESSION["usuario"]) devuelve = NULL`
Debería de obtener el valor, pero se pierde y me devuelve null ,este var_dump lo ejecute en la pagina que me reedirige , cabe destacar que no hay un header que te reediriga eso es porque lo estoy dirigiendo con ajax , pero antes funcionaba simplemente ahora no funciona y no entiendo el porque

Comment: No entiendo porque hacer un while para validar que tipo de sesion es pero bueno, a la pagina que intentas redirigir seguro que colocaste al inicio de todo ```session_start();``` ?

Comment: Revisa las cookies. Si usas algo en el navegador que no permita crearlas, la cookie del SESSIONID no va a llegar

Comment: revisa si hay algo que se escape al navegador antes de session_start() puedes hacerlo poniendo un echo y die despues de esa linea y si hay algo un espacio, salto de linea etc, puede que esa sea la causa, eso se revisa en ver codigo fuente no en la ventana normal del navegador.